# Call XAML animation from VB code in WPF

Tags: wpf, vb.net, events, xaml, animation

here's what I'm trying to do:

I have a Storyboard animation for an object done in Expression Blend. What I need is to be able to trigger that animation from the VB.net code. Any ideas?

Thanks,

EDIT:

Now I´m getting this error while trying to debug the app:

**Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Begin' accepts this number of arguments.**

"Begin" is the argument to start the Storyboard animation. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've just translated this C# (using a tool, I suck at VB.NET)

```
Storyboard myStoryboard = (Storyboard)FindResource("StoryboardName");
myStoryboard.Begin();
```

to this

```
Dim myStoryboard As Storyboard = DirectCast(FindResource("StoryboardName"), Storyboard)
myStoryboard.Begin()
```

This assumes the x:Key of your Storyboard is StoryboardName.

If not using .NET 3.5 **SP1** try

```
myStoryboard.Begin(me)
```

Answer (score 1):

If I am not mistaken, if you apply an x:Name attribute to the resource it will be accessible as a member property of the control and you can just call (assuming you used x:Name="myStoryBoard")

```
myStoryBoard.Begin()
```